# Tag size / encoding behaviour

Tags: android, encoding, nfc

I am quite new to Android NFC programming and I bought **NXP MIFARE Ultralight NTAG216** tags. They contain **886** free Bytes. In my app, I write tags with the following

```
public void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {
    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(records);
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    ndef.connect();
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    ndef.close();
}

private NdefRecord createRecord(String content) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang = "en";
    byte[] textBytes = content.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int langLength = langBytes.length;
    int textLength = textBytes.length;

    byte[] payload = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1, langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], payload);
    return recordNFC;
}
```

I need approximately 600 characters to store what I want on the tag.
The thing is that I cannot write more than 254 characters without this line freezing (It doesn't throw Exceptions, just tries to write)

```
ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
```

Using an app called NFC Tools, I can see that I use 254/886 Bytes of available data. I cannot write more on the tag using the App either, it also freezes.

I thought it was an encoding problem so I looked at the Android documentation [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html) and it looks like you can only write UTF-8 encoded data on tags. Maybe writing ASCII encoded data could save more space.

Does Android puts a limit on how many bytes you can write ?
Is it an encoding problem ? Can I directly write ASCII encoded text onto the tag ?
I'm really lost there. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is not a limit set by Android, but is probably a device-related bug. I ran into a similar issue with the Ulefone Armor 2 (running Android 7.0, kernel 4.4.15). The problem did not occur on other devices.

With regard to you remark about encoding as ASCII. Android also allows the NDEF record content to be encoded using ASCII as follows:

```
  byte[] dataBytes = token.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
  byte[] mimeBytes = VALIDATION_TAG_MIME_TYPE.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
  NdefRecord nfcRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, mimeBytes, null, dataBytes);
```